# How to compare last modified date and created date using WP_Query

Tags: wordpress

Following WP documentation at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters I am trying to create a query that displays only posts which have a post modified date that is different their post created date:

```
$latestedits = array(
    'post_type' => array('venue'),
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'orderby' => 'modified',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'column'     => 'post_modified_gmt',
            'column'   => 'post_date_gmt',
            'compare' => '>',
        ),
    ),
);
```

This is returning nothing however. Any ideas what I am doing wrong or how this can be achieved some other way?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it inside the loop.

You could do something along the lines of

```
$post_date = get_the_date( 'Ymd' );
$modified_date = get_the_date( 'Ymd' );
if( $modified_date && $post_date != $modified_date ){
     _do stuff_
}
```